# Replace NSInvocation with bool argument in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, swift3

I've the following code in objC:

```
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:shouldCloseSelector]) {
        // Create the invocation object
        ms = [delegate methodSignatureForSelector:shouldCloseSelector];
        inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:ms];

        // Set the target, selector, and parameters
        [inv setTarget:delegate];
        [inv setSelector:shouldCloseSelector];
        [inv setArgument:&windowController atIndex:2];
        [inv setArgument:&shouldClose atIndex:3];
        [inv setArgument:&contextInfo atIndex:4];

        // Invoke!
        [inv invoke];
```

}

I've no idea how I can translate this into Swift (3). `NSInvocation` is not available and the `performSelector` versions take only objects and only two arguments.

Using closures (the most suggested solution) is not an option as this is in an override of `NSDocument`'s `-(void)shouldCloseWindowController:(NSWindowController *)windowController delegate:(id)delegate shouldCloseSelector:(SEL)shouldCloseSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo`, so I'm out of control here.

How can I still call that selector on the delegate?

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032032/how-can-you-implement-the-nsdocument-method-canclosedocumentwithdelegateshould ?

Comment: That seems to work indeed! Many thanks.